# How does Rails know to not display a form that you don't have text_fields for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I just added some new `text_field`s to a form in Rails inside a `form_for` helper and now it's no longer showing the form after I refreshed the page with my changes. I think it's because the resource for this form does not have the new attributes yet so that's why it's not working, but I can't confirm this. The console just throws a 500. How would I go about debugging this?

Comment: Check your rails logs, what's the output?

Comment: please, share some code samples !

Comment: Share exacf error, 500 is server error code.